# Pass onPictureInPictureModeChanged result into a react native module

Tags: android, react-native, native, react-native-modules, bitmovin-player

I am trying to do some picture in picture mode using react-native. I wrote a react module

I need to generate something similar to this but inside the react native module

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private PlayerView playerView;
    private Player player;
    private boolean playerShouldPause = true;

...

    @Override
    public void onPictureInPictureModeChanged(boolean isInPictureInPictureMode, Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onPictureInPictureModeChanged(isInPictureInPictureMode, newConfig);

        // Hiding the ActionBar
        if (isInPictureInPictureMode) {
            getSupportActionBar().hide();
        } else {
            getSupportActionBar().show();
        }
        playerView.onPictureInPictureModeChanged(isInPictureInPictureMode, newConfig);
    }
...
}
```

There is some way to do it the same way but inside ReactContextBaseJavaModule

```
public class ReactNativeBitmovinPlayerModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {

...
 @Override
    public void onPictureInPictureModeChanged(boolean isInPictureInPictureMode, Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onPictureInPictureModeChanged(isInPictureInPictureMode, newConfig);

        // Hiding the ActionBar
        if (isInPictureInPictureMode) {
            getSupportActionBar().hide();
        } else {
            getSupportActionBar().show();
        }
        playerView.onPictureInPictureModeChanged(isInPictureInPictureMode, newConfig);
    }
...
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to achieve it. And there's actually more than one way to listen for PiP mode events from native modules.

### Quick way

The easiest way is by making your base java module a `LifecycleStateObserver` and checking changes on `Activity.isInPictureInPictureMode()` for every activity state update.

```java
public class ReactNativeCustomModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule implements LifecycleEventObserver {
  private boolean isInPiPMode = false;
  private final ReactApplicationContext reactContext;

  public ReactNativeCustomModule(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    super(reactContext);
    this.reactContext = reactContext;
  }

  private void sendEvent(String eventName, @Nullable WritableMap args) {
    reactContext
      .getJSModule(RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class)
      .emit(eventName, args);
  }

  @ReactMethod
  public void registerLifecycleEventObserver() {
    AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) reactContext.getCurrentActivity();
    if (activity != null) {
      activity.getLifecycle().addObserver(this);
    } else {
      Log.d(this.getName(), "App activity is null.");
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onStateChanged(@NonNull LifecycleOwner source, @NonNull Lifecycle.Event event) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
      AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) source;
      boolean isInPiPMode = activity.isInPictureInPictureMode();
      // Check for changes on pip mode.
      if (this.isInPiPMode != isInPiPMode) {
        this.isInPiPMode = isInPiPMode;
        Log.d(this.getName(), "Activity pip mode has changed to " + isInPiPMode);
        // Dispatch onPictureInPicutreModeChangedEvent to js.
        WritableMap args = Arguments.createMap();
        args.putBoolean("isInPiPMode", isInPiPMode)
        sendEvent("onPictureInPictureModeChanged", args);
      }
    }
  }
  // ...
}
```

Note it's impossible to register the lifecycle observer inside the module's constructor because the activity's still `null`. It needs to be registered on the javascript side.

Therefore, call `registerLifecycleEventObserver` at your component's initialization so it can start receiving activity state updates.

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { NativeEventEmitter, NativeModules } from 'react-native';

const ReactNativeCustomModule = NativeModules.ReactNativeCustomModule;
const eventEmitter = new NativeEventEmitter(ReactNativeCustomModule);

// JS wrapper.
export const CustomComponent = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    // Register module to receive activity's state updates.
    ReactNativeCustomModule.registerLifecycleEventObserver();
    const listener = eventEmitter.addListener('onPictureInPictureModeChanged', (args) => {
      console.log('isInPiPMode:', args.isInPiPMode);
    });
    return () => listener.remove();
  }, []);

  return (
    // jsx
  );
};
```

By the way, I opened a pull request on [`react-native-bitmovin-player`](https://github.com/take0ffmedia/react-native-bitmovin-player/pull/10) implementing this very feature. Please, check it out .

### Hard way

There's yet another way to listen for PiP changes, but it's more complex and requires a deeper knowledge of both android and RN platforms. However, with it, you get the advantage of accessing `newConfig` on the `onPictureInPictureModeChanged` method (if required) and not listening to any of the activity's lifecycle events.

Start by embedding your custom native view (whatever it is) into a [`Fragment`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment), then override the fragment's `onPictureInPictureModeChanged` method and finally dispatch an RN event there. Here's how it can be done step by step:

1. Create a fragment for your custom view:

```java
// Make sure to use android.app's version of Fragment if you need
// to access the `newConfig` argument.
import android.app.Fragment;

// If not, use androidx.fragment.app's version.
// This is the preferable way nowadays, but doesn't include `newConfig`.
// import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

// For the sake of example, lets use android.app's version here.
public class CustomViewFragment extends Fragment {
  interface OnPictureInPictureModeChanged {
    void onPictureInPictureModeChanged(boolean isInPictureInPictureMode, Configuration newConfig);
  }

  private CustomView customView;
  private OnPictureInPictureModeChanged listener;

  @Nullable
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    customView = new CustomView();
    // Do all UI setups needed for customView here.
    return customView;
  }

  // Android calls this method on the fragment everytime its activity counterpart is also called.
  @Override
  public void onPictureInPictureModeChanged(boolean isInPictureInPictureMode, Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onPictureInPictureModeChanged(isInPictureInPictureMode, newConfig);
    if (listener != null) {
      this.listener.onPictureInPictureModeChanged(isInPictureInPictureMode, newConfig);
    }
  }

  public void setOnPictureInPictureModeChanged(OnPictureInPictureModeChanged listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
  }

  // OnViewCreated, onPause, onResume, onDestroy...
}
```

2. Create an RN `ViewGroupManager` to hold the fragment and export
   functions and props to javascript:

```java
public class CustomViewManager extends ViewGroupManager<FrameLayout> implements CustomViewFragment.OnPictureInPictureModeChanged {
  public static final String REACT_CLASS = "CustomViewManager";
  public final int COMMAND_CREATE = 1;

  ReactApplicationContext reactContext;

  public CustomViewManager(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    this.reactContext = reactContext;
  }

  // Expose `onPictureInPictureModeChanged` prop to javascript.  
  public Map getExportedCustomBubblingEventTypeConstants() {
    return MapBuilder.builder().put(
      "onPictureInPictureModeChanged",
      MapBuilder.of(
        "phasedRegistrationNames",
         MapBuilder.of("bubbled", "onPictureInPictureModeChanged")
      )
    ).build();
  }

  @Override
  public void onPictureInPictureModeChanged(boolean isInPiPMode, Configuration newConfig) {
    Log.d(this.getName(), "PiP mode changed to " + isInPiPMode + " with config " + newConfig.toString());

    // Dispatch onPictureInPictureModeChanged to js.
    final WritableMap args = Arguments.createMap();
    args.putBoolean("isInPiPMode", isInPiPMode);
    args.putMap("newConfig", asMap(newConfig));
    reactContext
      .getJSModule(RCTEventEmitter.class)
      .receiveEvent(getId(), "onPictureInPictureModeChanged", args);
  }

  // Get the JS representation of a Configuration object.
  private ReadableMap asMap(Configuration config) {
    final WritableMap map = Arguments.createMap();
    map.putBoolean("isNightModeActive", newConfig.isNightModeActive());
    map.putBoolean("isScreenHdr", newConfig.isScreenHdr());
    map.putBoolean("isScreenRound", newConfig.isScreenRound());
    // ...
    return map;
  }

  @Override
  public String getName() {
    return REACT_CLASS;
  }

  @Override
  public FrameLayout createViewInstance(ThemedReactContext reactContext) {
    return new FrameLayout(reactContext);
  }

  // Map the "create" command to an integer
  @Nullable
  @Override
  public Map<String, Integer> getCommandsMap() {
    return MapBuilder.of("create", COMMAND_CREATE);
  }

  // Handle "create" command (called from JS) and fragment initialization
  @Override
  public void receiveCommand(@NonNull FrameLayout root, String commandId, @Nullable ReadableArray args) {
    super.receiveCommand(root, commandId, args);
    int reactNativeViewId = args.getInt(0);
    int commandIdInt = Integer.parseInt(commandId);
    switch (commandIdInt) {
      case COMMAND_CREATE:
        createFragment(root, reactNativeViewId);
        break;
      default: {}
    }
  }

  // Replace RN's underlying native view with your own
  public void createFragment(FrameLayout root, int reactNativeViewId) {
    ViewGroup parentView = (ViewGroup) root.findViewById(reactNativeViewId).getParent();
    // You'll very likely need to manually layout your parent view as well to make sure
    // it stays updated with the props from RN.
    //
    // I recommend taking a look at android's `view.Choreographer` and  RN's docs on how to do it.
    // And, as I said, this requires some knowledge of native Android UI development.
    setupLayout(parentView);

    final CustomViewFragment fragment = new CustomViewFragment();
    fragment.setOnPictureInPictureModeChanged(this);

    FragmentActivity activity = (FragmentActivity) reactContext.getCurrentActivity();
    // Make sure to use activity.getSupportFragmentManager() if you're using
    // androidx's Fragment.
    activity.getFragmentManager()
      .beginTransaction()
      .replace(reactNativeViewId, fragment, String.valueOf(reactNativeViewId))
      .commit();
  }
}
```

3. Register `CustomViewManager` in a package:

```java
public class CustomPackage implements ReactPackage {
  @Override
  public List<ViewManager> createViewManagers(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    return Arrays.<ViewManager>asList(
      new CustomViewManager(reactContext)
    );
  }
}
```

4. Implement the javascript side:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { UIManager, findNodeHandle, requireNativeComponent } from 'react-native';

const CustomViewManager = requireNativeComponent('CustomViewManager');

const createFragment = (viewId) =>
  UIManager.dispatchViewManagerCommand(
    viewId,
    UIManager.CustomViewManager.Commands.create.toString(), // we are calling the 'create' command
    [viewId]
  );

export const CustomView = ({ style }) => {
  const ref = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const viewId = findNodeHandle(ref.current);
    createFragment(viewId!);
  }, []);

  const onPictureInPictureModeChanged = (event) => {
    console.log('isInPiPMode:', event.nativeEvent.isInPiPMode);
    console.log('newConfig:', event.nativeEvent.newConfig);
  }

  return (
    <CustomViewManager
      style={{
        ...(style || {}),
        height: style && style.height !== undefined ? style.height || '100%',
        width: style && style.width !== undefined ? style.width || '100%'
      }}
      ref={ref}
      onPictureInPictureModeChanged={onPictureInPictureModeChanged}
    />
  );
};
```

This last example was heavily based on [RN's documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-components-android#1-create-a-fragment). And I can't stress enough how important it is to read it if you go the hard way.

Anyways, I hope this little guide may be of help.

Best regards.

Comment: Excelente @Murillo really appreciate your help, thanks again!!!!

Comment: glad I could help 

Comment: Thanks! I am using 1st implementation but    
```boolean isInPiPMode = activity.isInPictureInPictureMode();```
is always returning false;